# How to do a matplotlib tics in x-axis that the distance between tics is not constant?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have the situation that I have a data of values x and I am able to compute the time when data was collected. So every hour there might be 0 to n data points where I have to plot a bar using Matplotlib. I would like to set x scale tics such that one sees easily at what time the data was collected. How can I set the x-tics such that the distance between tics changes? I have managed to do the plot correctly except I haven't find a way to do the x-tics.

The idea is like

```
x0-tic to x1-tic contains bars 14.52.32-13.52.32:
34 14.52.32
34 14.50.00
54 14.20.00
12 13.52.34
x1-tic to x2-tic contains bars 13.52.32-12.52.32:
42 13.46.43
x2-tic to x3-tic contains bars 12.52.32-11.52.32
24 11.52.43
23 11.24.32
```

and so on.

I know how to do the bar plot but I don't know how to put a tick to x-axis  such that the tick is between fourth and fifth bar and between fifth and sixth bar like in the example data.

[image] Here is a quick and dirty demo showing that if suitable data has one measurement on first hour, two on the second hour, three on the third hour, two on the fourth hour then between 3h and 2h there should be more bars than between 2h and 1h bars but the width of the bars stays the same.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also include a picture of how you would like the plot to look?

Comment: Minimal would be hard as it is a part of larger program so it won't be complete. Also, I have never tried code golfing so I don't know how to write minimal programs.